Nginx config not working with removing .php from url
I am having trouble with the Nginx default config for my website. My PHP website runs on a linux azure machine, which uses nginx. This is currently my config:
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    # dont show /index, index.php
    if ( $request_uri ~ "/index" ) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/ $1/ permanent;
    }

    # remove .php from url
    if ($request_uri ~ \.php($|\?))
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    # remove www. from url
    if ($host ~ '^www\.') {
        return 301 https://exmaple.com$request_uri;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}

All I try to achieve is to remove .php from the url, which is working with this config. Atleast thats what i thought.. When I got to mysite.com/register.php it shows the page and the url looks like mysite.com/register, nice. But my form:
<form action="register.php" method="post"

this fails to work. action register.php or just register both don't work. When i remove the .php rewrite it works fine. Does somebody know whats going wrong in my config? Thanks in advance.

"this fails to work ... both don't work" - what does that mean?  Do you get an error when you submit?  If so, what is the error?

That’s the thing I don’t get any error at all. The form just submits and refreshes the page. When I remove the rewrite it executes as the register code it should do.

[sf] or [unix.se] are better places to ask questions about NGINX configuration.

This part:
if ($request_uri ~ \.php($|\?))
{
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
}

removes the .php part of the original request using an HTTP 301 status. Most browsers will retry the request with the modified URL, but are required to change a POST to a GET.
HTTP 307 status is similar, but the browser should retry a POST request with another POST request.
Try changing the if block to:
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\.php(\?.*)?$)
{
    return 307 $1$2;
}


This did not fix the problem. The config still makes the forms useless. When I submit the form, it just refreshes the page without actually executing the form logic. When i remove the rewrite, the form works fine.
